# run nant build file in command prompt using c#

Tags: c#, nant, command-prompt

I have a build file with nant now all I need to do is execute it with command prompt using c#
I tried the below but I am not able to build it ..

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("exe -buildfile:d:\buildfile.build);
```

and when I am running through cmd prompt directly it is working

Answer (score 2):

Have you setup nant as an environment variable?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("nant.exe -buildfile:d:\buildfile.build);
```

Comment: no can u tell me how to set the environment i am just specifing the nant path like "D:\\nant\\bin\\Nant.exe /build D:\\\buildfile.build

Comment: its should work if you are specifying the full path -- whats the error message you are getting?

Update your PATH environment variable to include <nant dir>\bin (for my setup, that's C:\nant-0.86\bin). 

see this article for managing environment variables -- http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/environment_variables.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: you could also rename you buildfile.build to be default build -- then you do not have to specifiy  -buildfile:d:\buildfile.build        
Just run NANT in the directory